# Why does moving a var (that looks, acts, and smells like a const) to an external file not get retrieved?

Tags: jquery, html, razor, webmatrix

WebMatrix's report on my app said I had too much script in my (Default.cshtml) file. So I moved a bunch of functions over to an external .js file and added a reference to it in Default.cshtml. That worked fine. But then, I thought I'd add some big placeholder html over there, too, so that I could do this in Default.cshtml:

```
$('#MusicContent').html(placeholderForGrammies);
```

...instead of this:

```
var placeholderForGrammies = "<div class=\"yearBanner\">2013</div><section class=\"wrapper\" ><a id=\"A16\" class=\"floatLeft\" href=\"<a href= . . . 10 gazillion bytes elided ...</section>";
$('#MusicContent').html(placeholderForGrammies);
```

...and thus skinny up my Default.cshtml file even more. But it doesn't work. Why does Default.cshtml see my functions in my .js file, but not my var?

Comment: Are you doing "var placeholder" on the outermost indentation level of the external file, or is it indented in some sort of window.ready?

Comment: It's not in a ready handler; should it be? None of the other things that are called by Default.cshtml's ready handler are.